# Passing variables through 3 pages

Tags: php, forms, variables, post, authentication

I've spent a lot of time looking for something that could help me doing this:
I have 3 pages, one called login.php, another called trataLogin.php and another called index.php.

The login and trataLogin page is working perfectly but when I try to call a variable into the index.php from login I can't do it.. I don't know what else to do it.

This is my login.php

```
     <?php
    require_once('connection/dbconnection.php');
    session_start();
    ?>
...
    <form name="form" action="trataLogin.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" /><br/>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" /><br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="login" />
    </form>
```

trataLogin.php

```
<?php
require_once('connection/dbconnection.php');
session_start();
$_SESSION['dadoslogin']=$_POST;


$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = sha1($_POST['password']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM utilizadores WHERE username = '" . $username . "' AND password = '" . $password . "'";
$admin='';
$result = $conn->query($query);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $_SESSION['verifica_login'];

    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    if ($row['admin'] == 1) {
        $admin = true;
        header('Location:admin.php');

    } elseif($row['admin'] == 0){
        $admin = false;
        header('Location:index.php');

    } else {
    $_SESSION['verifica_login']="Username ou password incorretos";
}}
?>
```

and in index.php I have this

```
<?php
require_once('connection/dbconnection.php');
session_start();
$_SESSION['dadoslogin']=$_POST;
?>
```

and somewhere below in index.php I've something that it was suppose to print the username of the person who logged in

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>
```

Comment: Put the sesssion_start() first in every page, before *any* code.

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting your `$_SESSION` in index.php:
Remove that part

```
$_SESSION['dadoslogin']=$_POST;
```

And echo your variable like this:

```
echo $_SESSION['dadoslogin']['username'];
```